# Excel VBA web-scraping working half of the time

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a VBA program used to scrape specific data from online real estate listings.  I will add the code below.  It searches the HTML code to return elements including Address, Year built, features, etc...

```
Sub GetAddress()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim address As Variant

'would prefer to reference a cell that already has a url, e.g. A1
website = Range("A1")

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "Get", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

'the class associated with the inormation I'm searching for is unsetH1, and there is only one instance of this class in the html
address = html.getElementsByClassName("unsetH1")(0).innerText

'return address to cell B1
Range("B1") = address


Dim yearbuilt As Variant


'cell A1 contains a url to search
website = Range("A1")

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
request.Open "Get", website, False
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

'this line etiher causes error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set, or error 424 - object required
yearbuilt = html.getElementById("propertyDetailsSectionContentSubCon_BuiltIn").getElementsByClassName("propertyDetailsSectionContentValue")(0).innerText

'return address to cell C1
Range("C1") = yearbuilt
```

This is only a portion of the code.  The rest of it repeats to find other elements just by changing class name and Id.

My problem is that the code sometimes works, and then without changing anything and then testing it again, it returns an error (runtime 91 - object variable or with block not set)

clues

- it usually works after opening the excel program and immediately running it, but if I run it again after a successful attempt, the second one will not work
- it says that the error occurs in the getElementby... lines, but I don't understand how that line can work perfectly one time, but then fail the next.

I am fairly new to programming, so perhaps there is a simple/obvious solution that I am missing. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

*Update*

More facts about the website (realor.ca)

- Example listing - https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/24551273/604-freeman-crescent-kingston
- no login necessary
- while specifics vary between individual listings, html classes and ids remain constant.

Comment: Did you try adding a debug.print of the response status code? Also, please don't auto-instantiate the MSHTML.HTMLDocument instance. Use  Dim html as MSHTML.HTMLDocument and later Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument to avoid weird behaviour popping up.

Comment: You can try looping until `.readystate = 4` after `.send` - something like `Do Until request.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @dbmitch, but the problem persists.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, thank for taking the time to answer.  Not quite sure how I should implement your suggestion, I'm quite new to programming so maybe you could provide more details? Thanks!

Comment: What is website url

Comment: https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/24551273/604-freeman-crescent-kingston  This url (or a url to a different listing on the same site) will be in cell A1

Comment: Do you have to login? Does it use cookies? I get access denied. Please update your question with all the facts

Comment: updated.  not sure why your access is denied, I've never encountered any issues like that.

Comment: I think they have some kind of blocking going on. I get an IFrame error now

Comment: Website is protected by Incapsula (now part of Imperva FlexProtect). As a minimum it detects your IP, unsure at present what other fingerprinting may occur. You could try rotating proxies. However, do check T&C of site as seems possible they don't want scraping.

Comment: Besides blocking, it is also the case on such websites that not all elements are present on all retrieved pages. If a missing element is accessed without cross-checking, an object error occurs.